# convert an array of bytes into a input stream in a xul plugin

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul, xpcom

I am working on a xul firefox-extension and have a binary value that I want to write to a file using `NetUtil.asyncCopy`. I have the data in an array of byte values, and need to convert it into an `nsIInputStream` so that asyncCopy can accept it.

I know from [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/File_I_O#Writing_to_a_file) that I can convert a string to a `nsIInputStream` using

```
Components.classes["@mozilla.org/intl/scriptableunicodeconverter"].
     createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableUnicodeConverter);
```

But cannot find any corresponding method to convert an array to an inputstream. Is there an approach that will allow me to do that? (or a different workaround)

Comment: Kudos for using something async. However, you'd still need to open/close the file on the main thread. Maybe you'll find [`OS.File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File), which really does all I/O off the main thread suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a particularly profound answer, but [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Firefox_addons_developer_guide/Using_XPCOM%E2%80%94Implementing_advanced_processes#Outputting_binary_files) provides an alternative path to saving the values. It is at the expense of doing the write synchronously, but in my case I can deal with that.